# How to handle error in nodejs behind nginx?

Tags: node.js, nginx, error-handling

I have nodejs/expressjs application that handles behind nginx. In the expressjs application I have the following error handling middleware:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.status(404);

  // respond with json
  if (req.accepts('json')) {
    res.send({ error: 'Not found' });
    return;
  }

  // respond with html page
  if (req.accepts('html')) {
    res.render('404', { url: req.url });
    return;
  }

  // default to plain-text. send()
  res.type('txt').send('Not found');
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  res.status(err.status || 500);

  // respond with json      
  if (req.accepts('json')) {
    res.send({ error: 'Not found' });
    return;
  }

  // respond with html page
  if (req.accepts('html')) {
    res.render('500', { error: err });
    return;
  }

  res.type('txt').send('Internal error');
});
```

Also in nginx I have the following config for error handling:

```
error_page 404 /404.html;
location = /404.html {
  internal; 
  root /path/to/static/html/;
}

error_page 400 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;         
location /50x.html {                 
  internal;                 
  root /path/to/static/html/;         
}
```

When I try to send some error by nodejs likes the following

```
res.status(500).json({error: 'Something happened'});
```

this error handles nginx and I get full html error page response instead json response. I think this is due the following nginx config:

```
error_page 400 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;         
location /50x.html {                 
  internal;                 
  root /path/to/static/html/;         
}
```

How could I setup nginx to handle only errors that not handled by nodejs server?

Thanks.

Comment: Show full nginx config

Comment: My nginx config looks like the following https://gist.github.com/cosbynator/3072833 except adding the error handling blocks as above.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have `proxy_intercept_errors` somewhere

Comment: My config looks the followinghttps://gist.github.com/bsphere/4501965#file-myapp_nginx

Comment: No I have no `proxy_intercept_errors` directive. Does resolve my problem?

Comment: This line https://gist.github.com/bsphere/4501965#file-myapp_nginx-L41 tells nginx to intercept errors from upstream and handle them

Comment: Is it possible to intercept only errors with specific http codes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using `proxy_intercept_errors on` directive. In order to intercept only certain error codes, just add `error_page` directive(s) to location with proxy. Otherwise they are inherited.

Here we only intercept only 400 and 502 errors, everything else will pass through to client.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://myapp_upstream;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 400 502 /50x.html;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. May you advise best production practices for error handling? What error codes should intersect by using nginx?

Comment: It depends on your application.

Comment: Is it possible to check if response is json then handle error by using node js but if html then handle by using nginx?

Comment: I don't know. Guess not

Comment: You can check if the client sent the accept header for JSON, which might be enough: if ($http_accept ~ json) {// JSON response}